# Laravel | Special validation of a lot of data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, validation

## Validation of a data (1 - 10000 possible rows)

So to give some context I am creating a web based mapping interface to map other data formats to our format.

### Problem

Taking an array of data and an array of formats like this:

```
$vehicle = [
    'cost' => '$159',
    'reconditioning' => '$140'
];

$formats = [
    'cost' => 'integer',
    'reconditioning' => 'integer'
];
```

And checking all of the fields for inconsistencies with our data structure, like "total_cost" would be an error in the data since it has a non-numeric character in it. The output of the validation would have to show an error for each individual field like shown below (true meaning that that field has an error):

```
$vehicle_errors = [
    'total_cost' => true, 
    're_condition' => true
];
```

Which after the validation, I am displaying the fields that had errors for the user to correct them.

I have succeeded in doing all of this but I was using for-loops and a switch case to validate each individual field, this becomes a problem when we get more than a few thousand vehicles.

### What I've Tried

I have tried using for-loops to accomplish this with success but php required me to increase the "max_input_vars" to a lot which I would like to try to avoid because this operation heavily taxed my server.
I have also tried Laravels validation which didnt give me the output I wanted and also had the same problem as using for-loops did, with the php error.

### Possible Solutions

I know that there is a way to validate data in a mysql table and get an output similar to what I need, this would fix my problem due to it using the mysql servers resources but I do not have any idea of how to accomplish this and couldn't find anything online about this topic.

Comment: Break the array into chunks.

Comment: If your input is using up too much memory, [generators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) are probably the simplest solution, as they have a much lower overheard when iterating over lots of content.

Comment: no matter the solution, break you request into multiple ones. make a front side progress bar with an ajax call for each 100 entry (for example) and show the result in the end (at 100%)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I will be trying to use generators as @MatthewDaly suggested, I will update this post with my results.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Could you offer some sort of sample code showing how I could use this to solve my data validation problem? I have been looking around for awhile now and trying different methods but I dont completely understand how this would offer a way of sorting through the vehicles while executing the logic for validation. I read the documentation you linked from the php website but I dont completely understand how to apply the examples they provided to this issue.

Comment: @AndrewGosselin Generators are just a way to iterate through something without loading the whole thing into memory. If you are using the new Laravel 6 or can upgrade to it, the new lazy collections would simplify this a lot

Comment: @AndrewGosselin Found an example at https://www.magutti.com/blog/laravel-lazy-collections, so maybe you can adapt that for your use case. With the lazy collections you should be able to iterate over your records by using your switch/case statement on each element, and either throw an exception or trigger an event as appropriate when a row fails validation.

Comment: @AndrewGosselin Also, is this the best approach? Would it maybe make more sense for users to upload a file somewhere else, such as a Dropbox folder or S3 bucket that you can access via the Storage API, and set up a webhook or event notification that triggers a queued task in your application? You could even just have your upload handler copy the file somewhere else, then trigger a queued job to handle the processing separately. This kind of processing is best done outside the context of an HTTP request if possible.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Thanks for the solution, the example you gave me worked perfectly, I honestly had no idea this was added in the newest version of Laravel. Could you please post that as an answer so I can mark this as complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your fundamental problem in this case is that the array of data is too large to load into memory in one go, so your application is crashing once the array gets too big.

[Generators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) were added to PHP to solve this problem. They allow you to iterate over a set of data without needing to hold the whole thing in memory, making it more practical to work with very large datasets. However, the syntax can be a bit cumbersome.

As it happens, the newly released Laravel 6 offers a solution to this problem in the form of [lazy collections](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#lazy-collections). These use generators, but provide a friendlier interface so that you can easily iterate through very large data sets without using too much memory. Here's an example of it in use, taken from https://www.magutti.com/blog/laravel-lazy-collections:

```
use App\Project;
use Illuminate\Support\LazyCollection;


Route::get('/', function () {

    LazyCollection::make(function () {
        // project.csv  with 300.000 rows
        $filePath = storage_path('app/public/project.csv');
        $handle = fopen($filePath, 'r');
        while ($line = fgetcsv($handle)) {
            yield $line;
        }
    })
        ->chunk(10000) //split in chunk to reduce the number of queries
        ->each(function ($lines) {

            $list = [];
            foreach ($lines as $line) {
                if (isset($line[1])) {
                    $list[] = [
                        'name' => $line[1],
                        'email' => $line[2],
                        'status_id' => $line[3]
                    ];
                }
            }
            // insert 10000 rows in one shot
            Project::insert($list);

        });
    /* display memory usage */
    echo number_format(memory_get_peak_usage() / 1048576, 2) . ' MB';
});
```

The Eloquent ORM also now returns a lazy collection when you call the `cursor()` method, so you can use that to handle very large sets of data returned from the database as well. All of this is achievable with generators alone, but lazy collections provide an easier and more readable way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use chunk.

```
DB::table('formats')->chunk(100, function($formats)
{
    foreach ($formats as $format)
    {
        //perform validation
    }
});
```

You'll also likely want to do this in a command as opposed to on a request to avoid timeouts and stuff. Depending on your setup, you could also create jobs in a queue for each item or just the ones that fail validation if the fix is intensive

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I am not pulling the data via a database query which is where I could use chunk. Also I need to display the errors afterwards on the same page, so I would not be able to use a command.

Comment: Ah, I see. So, the user is making a request and then your application grabs this data from an external service or scrapes it from somewhere?

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot to explain that part, the user is uploading a CSV file and that is parsed into an array of vehicles.

Comment: In that case, I would probably still not handle this all on a single request. I would offload this on to a queue and handle it with a worker. 

I would probably store the .csv have a table of rows that represented import jobs that had a column for total row count, processed row count, path to the csv, a json object to contain errors/messages that will need to be presented to the user, and a status enum, and then create a job to handle the import. Then, depending on the traffic, amount of jobs etc. either send the user to a page with their jobs, or just throw up a progress bar

Comment: how to validate in for loop ? :/